Getting real-time data from mongodb
I am trying to create an API to get the latest document from mongodb and show it in the browser. Showing the newest document only works if I refresh the browser. I am trying to make a dashboard with Temperature,Humidity and EC values update automatically using this endpoint.
This is my code for the API using Node.js.
const app = express();

//middle ware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const port = ;

// to specify in which db to save write the DB name before "?retryWrites"
const uri = '';


const sensorSchema = { 
    temperature: Number,
    humidity: Number,
    ec: Number,
    date: Date,
};

const Sensor = new mongoose.model("Sensor",sensorSchema); 

app.listen(port,()=>
{
    console.log(`Server started at http://localhost:${port}`)
});

const pipeline = [ { $match: { runtime: { $lt: 15 } } } ];

app.get('/get-readings', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Find the latest sensor reading
        const latestDoc = await Sensor.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { date: -1 } });
        res.json(latestDoc)

        const update = Sensor.watch(pipeline);

        for (const change of update) {

            console.log("Received change:\n", change);
            //res.json(change)

        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching sensor data:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});


const connectDB  = async () =>
{
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(uri);
        console.log('MongoDB connected');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
connectDB();

Latest document looks like this:

Using the MongoDB.watch() works but only if i console.log the newest document. If I uncomment the res.json(change) this is going to trigger an error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".
Any help or pointers on how to deal with would be appreciated.

Why don't you handle via notification. Like if any update happens in mongo DB, you publish a message and one(UI) who is listening to this notifcation can update dynamically.Then, you don't need to query to mongo DB.  Please check if you can follow this approach

You have a few options here.

Periodic Polling
Socket/TCP Stream
Webhook

I suggest doing some independent reading on this, but essentially they're all ways for you to more frequently receive data from some service.
The easiest one to implement would be the Periodic Polling -- you could just run the client code on an interval.
The socket approach would be the best if you require lots of communication and quick feedback between client and server. Check out https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#netcreateconnection. You can also take a look at t his approach https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http2.html#server-side-example
The webhook would only work for server to server communications as it would require you to expose an endpoint to receive data that gets "pushed" to you
